# Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'scaled'

Tags: swift, cgrect

I'm trying to use `detectLandmarks` in swift4 but appear an error at `let faceBoundingBox = boundingBox.scaled(to: self.view.bounds.size)`

Anyone know how to fix it

```
func detectLandmarks(on image: CIImage) {
    try? faceLandmarksDetectionRequest.perform([faceLandmarks], on: image)
    if let landmarksResults = faceLandmarks.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
        for observation in landmarksResults {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let boundingBox = self.faceLandmarks.inputFaceObservations?.first?.boundingBox {
                    let faceBoundingBox = boundingBox.scaled(to: self.view.bounds.size)

                    //different types of landmarks
                    let faceContour = observation.landmarks?.faceContour
                    self.convertPointsForFace(faceContour, faceBoundingBox)    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say there is an error... and yet, you do not tell us what this error is. (Put the error into the question). :D

Comment: CGRect, indeed, does not have a `scaled` member. Maybe it's from a framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try adding in this extension](https://github.com/KrauseFx/watch.user/blob/master/watch.user/CGRect%2BScaled.swift) into your code and things should build nicely:

```
//
//  CGRectExtension.swift
//  Vision Face Detection
//
//  Created by Pawel Chmiel on 23.06.2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Droids On Roids. All rights reserved.
//
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension CGRect {
    func scaled(to size: CGSize) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(
            x: self.origin.x * size.width,
            y: self.origin.y * size.height,
            width: self.size.width * size.width,
            height: self.size.height * size.height
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thinks I will have a try

Comment: This implementation is unlikely to be correct given how it is used in the code in the question. This answer seem to assume the `size` parameter is a scale factor (likely in the range 0.1 -> 2.0). But the question is passing in what appears to be a view controller's view's size.